# mvc form submit datetime field not recognising the format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have input field that takes dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm format e.g. 31/12/2018 21:05 
but when this gets submitted to the post action it doesn't bind to datetime class.

```
<input name="startDate" type="text" class="form-control m-input" readonly="" value="31/12/2018 21:05">
```

And my viewmodel attribute is like this

```
public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
```

if I change the above type to string it works fine .... or if I pass the input data in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm format it binds to DateTime type okay.
I have tried putting below annotation but still no luck.

```
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
```

I'm not using the helper class it's just an input field in html.
I could take it as a string field and convert to datetime but wonder whether there is any easier way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way.

Your input control contains a text representation of a date and time. Your model property needs a `DateTime` object. You have to convert one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the hour format which is "hh" but the input value is "21:05".

This line works fine:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/2018 21:05", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But gives the same error if the format is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"

**Edit**

You have been updated the topic and I from what I understand you have a few options to choose here. One is to receive the value as string and parse it or just create a customer ModelBinder, here is one example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1078167/DateTime-Issue-In-MVC

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because of your current culture settings (if you change value of `StartDate` textbox to `2018-12-31 21:05` it should work). Add `en-GB` (for example) culture to your Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
</system.web>
```